# 18.10 - Ubuntu switching to single display when it boot up

Tags: display, 18.10, multiple-monitors

I'm currently having the following problem:

When Ubuntu boots up, one of mine monitors turns black (I will call it monitor A), and the other one shows me the login screen (Monitor B). After I complete the login, the monitor A keeps black, and the Monitor B behaves as a second monitor (It does not appear the task bar, etc), but I can drag things from the side of the screen into it.

When I open the display options, it is set into "Single Display Mode", and I have to disconnect and reconnect one of my monitors to be able to change it back into "Join Displays mode"

To be more specific about my Setup:

- Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G3240 @ 3.10GHz.
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Desktop.
- Both monitors are plugged directly into my motherboard, one in DVI and
  the other on the VGA.
- I've just istalled Ubuntu, so I don't know if it is specific from 18.10 or not.

Some command outputs that maybe helpful:

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2732 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      60.02  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 connected 1366x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 409mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1360x768      60.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**lspci | grep -i vga**

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Thanks for your time!